# matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как сделать что бы при отсутствии объекта в базе выводилось не исключение `DoesNotExists` а что бы выводился мой текст ошибки.

```py
class SearchCityView(ListView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'cities/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'city'
    form_class = CityForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Поиск'
        context['city_form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            city_name = self.request.GET.get('name')
            return City.objects.get(name__iexact=city_name)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse('Не найдено')
```

Ищет город в базе, если есть то выводит его, если нету то выводит DoesNotexists, а надо что бы над формами просто сообщение выводилось что город не найден.

Comment: Функция называется `get_queryset`, возвращаете вы либо экземпляр модели, либо http-ответ. Почему вы подумали, что так можно? По этому клочку кода очень непросто разобраться в сути, я бы советовал чуть больше подробностей включить... хотя бы, чей это метод и какое `view`...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что пытаетесь реализовать. Это страница будет показывать один город или несколько? Если один - то неправильный выбор базового класса (`ListView` - для списка), если не один - то неправильная реализация `get_queryset` - `City.objects.get` возвращает один объект. Так что опишите, что вы хотите тут реализовать.

Comment: Причем тут базовый класс список может быть и с 1 элементом. Мне надо выводить свое сообщение об ошибке а не исключение DoesNotExists.

Answer (score 0):

В строке `except ObjectDoesNotExist:` используйте `City.DoesNotExist`.